# How to change the colour of nav bar in react native

Tags: android, css, react-native, frontend

Also what is it called in the documentation? I searched a lot and I think it should be called navigation bar, but I could not find any reference to any navigation bar

This is what I am talking about.. it is at the bottom of my android device and does not respect any theming. I have it as a straight line but sometimes it is also in the form of 3 buttons
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't find anything in the react native docs, this is what I found on the expo docs
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/

This is what is used to control the colour of the bar and also visibility. I dont know if this is a thing with just my phone but changing the colour wont change all of it, just a faint border... but hiding it works fine

Here are the steps I used

1. Add the dependency

```sh
yarn add expo-navigation-bar
```

2. Just do whatever after that, what I did was hide so first import it

```js
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";
```

3. Modify the navigation bar

```js
NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync("hidden");
```

Edit: I had a typo in my code because of which the background colour change was not working. After fixing that it does work

[image: Background Colour]

Answer (score 0):

To do this, there are several npm libraries.
The react-native-navigation-bar-color is my recommendation

Comment: I tried the library but it does not work, and the actual code it uses also does not seem to have any reference on the docs. It imports some native modules and gets the nav bar colour from the native modules, and then uses some built in functions on that object to change the colour. I tried the library and also tried just stripping the code from the library's source code to use as is but neither worked. is there any other library which you know of?

Comment: @ThePiGuy There is also react-native-navbar-color. Let's hope this works for you.

Comment: I think I found the solution to it, I am using expo-navigation-bar which has good documentation and everything to go with it. Using this because the boilerplate for expo init had expo-status-bar so I was just a bit curious and tried finding for more